# Create Hunt Group with Twilio Twiml

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am trying to create a basic hunt group using Twiml.

pseudo code:

```
Dial 'Number1' for 'timeout=10 seconds'

If 'DialCallStatus' not 'completed' then 

Dial 'Number2' for 'timeout=10 seconds'

If 'DialCallStatus' not 'completed' then 

Dial 'Number3' for 'timeout=10 seconds'

If 'DialCallStatus' not 'completed' then 

Hangup Call
```

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: I tried looping these together: https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/forward but didn't have much luck.  Suprising that you have Forward/Simulring/Findme but no option for Hunting!

Comment: I'd rather do this in Twiml though so I can build and edit the code.  But I can't figure out how to trigger the next call.  Do you have to add a URL to another Twiml.  And nest them?

Comment: I have started with: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial timeout='5' >
    NUMBER1
  </Dial>
</Response>

Comment: Isn't Findme the same as Hunt?

Comment: Yes, you're right :-)  we need to be able to send we hooks on answer though, so I guess we need twiml instead of twimlets.  Are you able to help me write some code for this?

Comment: I can point you in the right direction, but I can't write the code for you. Give it a go, and if you get stuck with a particular part, then ask a question here and tag it twilio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150100/discussion-between-marcus-and-philnash).

Comment: philnash has answered this in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45306471/3693688